# Python rotatingfilehandler logging in multiple modules without defining a logger

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple Python program which consists of the following modules:

```
python_project/
├── module_a.py
├── module_b.py
├── run.py
└── settings.py
```

`setting.py` contains a function for `logging` settings as follows:

```
# settings.py

import logging

def setup_logging(logger_name, level):
    # configure global logger
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file,
                        level=level,
                        format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
```

With this setup, I am able to issue log messages from every module simply by using `logging`. This is how `run.py` looks like for example :

```
# run.py

from settings import setup_logging

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

        setup_logging(logger_name='my_logger')

    def start_processing():
        logging.info('Starting processing')
        # more code here ...
```

However, I am not able to log messages calling `logging.info()`  for example with `rotatingfilehandler`.

My question is: can I setup a rotating file logging and then log messages using `logging`, e.g. `logging.info()`, from any module without 
specifying something like `logger = logging.getLogger('my_rotatingfilelogger')`?